# Random groups of runners being assigned trophies, combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> In a race with 30 runners where 8 trophies will be given to the top 8
>   runners (the trophies are distinct: first place, second place, etc),
>   how many ways can this be done?

$$\\$$

I would have done $30*29*28*27*26*25*24*23$, but the website where I found this exercise says the solution is $^{30}C_8 * 8$.

Why is that? Shouldn't the order count in this case?

Comment: maybe the "!" sign at the end has been mistyped : $^{30}C_8 * 8!$ would be the same as your answer.

Comment: @GCab Maybe. You can check the source of the question for yourself: http://www.imsc.res.in/~kamalakshya/cupboard/comb_mag.pdf it's question 14

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's a typo on the website. It should be 
$^{30}C_8*8!$ instead of $^{30}C_8*8$

The answer is:
$$30∗29∗28∗27∗26∗25∗24∗23=^{30}C_8∗8!$$